# Where in statute are the grounds of section 8 eviction notices spelled out?

Tags: england-and-wales, landlord, tenant, tenancy-rules

I'd like to find the original statutory source for all of the respective parameters of different section 8 eviction grounds, for assured shorthold tenancies in England & Wales.

I read [section 8](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1988/50/section/8) of the [Housing Act 1988](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1988/50/contents) on legislation.gov, but surprisingly to no avail.

Comment: What's wrong with this one?

Comment: I've looked in section 8 of housing act 1988 and surprisingly enough I could not find the grounds defined!

Comment: C3nd comment? ?

Comment: Please cite,, and if possible link to,, the statute in question. Many laws have a "section 8" and the only one i recall  being refereed to like that was the regulation allowing dismissal from the US Army, which I don't think is your referant here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User xngtng's answer already answers the question, but to add a little more detail:

The full list of grounds appears in [Schedule 2](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1988/50/schedule/2) to the [Housing Act 1988](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1988/50/contents). The Schedule's title is "Grounds for Possession of Dwelling-houses let on Assured Tenancies".

Most of the rules associated with those grounds are contained in section 7 of the Act ("Orders for possession") and the eponymous section 8 ("Notice of proceedings for possession"). Sections 8A, 9, 9A, 10A, 11 and 12 add further details relating to particular grounds, and there are occasional references to the Schedule elsewhere in the Act too.

Comment: Excellent answer.

Answer (score 4):

Section 8 of the Housing Act 1988 provides that

> (2) The court shall not make an order for possession on any of the grounds in **[Schedule 2 to this Act](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1988/50/schedule/2)** unless that ground and particulars of it are specified in the notice under this section; but the grounds specified in such a notice may be altered or added to with the leave of the court.

Section 7 of the same Act also provides that

> (1) The court shall not make an order for possession of a dwelling-house let on an assured tenancy except on one or more of the grounds set out in Schedule 2 to this Act; [...]